# React Native gradient shadow

Tags: react-native, shadow, linear-gradients

I'm adding a shadow to an image, and it works fine but I want the shadow to be gradient like in this picture (from dark to bright ) :

[image]

In the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html) shadow Props doesn't have such property, so is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how Expo is doing it but we've used the react-native-linear-gradient for things like that

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Comment: thanks, but I've already tried it and it's not working, it show me a red rectangle without any gradient.

Comment: Yes, it'll do that if you haven't installed it correctly.  You might have to also restart the packager.

Comment: Well I restarted the packager, but same thing :(

Comment: It seems I missed some configurations, it work's fine now.